# Rails - DRY out similar views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two partials which have similar outputs but major changes.

- Partial 1

  ```
  <h2 class="text-center">Current Incident</h2>
  <% active_incidents.each do |i| %>
  <div class="incident-block">
    <p class="incident-date"><span class="inner-date"><%= i.updated_at.strftime('%e %b, %Y') %></span></p>

    <span class="incident-name text-<%= i.convert_to_level %>"><%= i.name %>
      <% if signed_in? %><a href="/incidents/deactivate/<%= i.id %>">
      <button class="btn btn-success deactivate-button btn-xs">Deactivate incident</button>
    </a>
      <% end %></span>
    <span class="incident-component text-<%= i.convert_to_level %>"><%= i.component %></span>
    <% all_events(i).each do |e| %>
        <hr class="event-hr"/>
        <p class="incident-description"><b><%= e.status %></b>- &nbsp;<%= e.message %></p>

        <p class="incident-updated-at"><%= e.updated_at.strftime('%b %e, %H:%M %Z') %></p>
    <% end %>

    <% if signed_in? %>
        <a href="/incidents/<%= i.id %>">
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Update Incident</button>
        </a>
        <a href="/incidents/delete/<%= i.id %>" data-confirm="Are you sure? Deleting an incident is irreversible.">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete Incident</button>
        </a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
   <% end %>
  ```
- Partial 2

  ```
  <% if inactive_incidents.any? %><h2 class="text-center">Past Incidents</h2><% end %>
  <% inactive_incidents.each do |i| %>
      <div class="incident-block">
    <p class="incident-date"><span class="inner-date"><%= i.updated_at.strftime('%e %b, %Y') %></span></p>
    <span class="incident-name text-<%= i.convert_to_level %>"><%= i.name %></span><span class="incident-component text-<%= i.convert_to_level %>"><%= i.component %></span>
    <% all_events(i).each do |e| %>
        <hr class="event-hr"/>
        <p class="incident-description"><b><%= e.status %></b>- &nbsp;<%= e.message %></p>

        <p class="incident-updated-at"><%= e.updated_at.strftime('%b %e, %H:%M %Z') %></p>
    <% end %>

    <% if signed_in? %>
        <a href="/incidents/<%= i.id %>">
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Update Incident</button>
        </a>
        <a href="/incidents/delete/<%= i.id %>" data-confirm="Are you sure? Deleting an incident is irreversible.">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete Incident</button>
        </a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
   <% end %>
  ```

Now, these partials house similar code but with significant changes that render differing output. Since code maintainability is becoming an issue for me now (I have to make all changes twice). How do I DRY-out the code but still maintain the differing logic?

Comment: Just in case anyone needs more context, [here's the source](https://github.com/ur0/statusify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each one, create a template.  Then take your common code in the middle and put it in a partial.  Call the partial from each template and send the incidents in as a local variable.  Like so inside the template:

```
<%= render partial: 'incidents', locals: { incidents: inactive_incidents } %>
```

You could even call a partial for each incident using collection.

Also if you differ logic inside the common partial, you can use helpers to toggle that logic based on a passed local variable or other.  Leverage that and perhaps content_tag should help.

I suggest reading the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials